# Using select dropdown to go to different webpages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make these section go to specific pages but not sure where to go from here. Can someone help me please with sample url pages. Here is my code:

```html
<div style="background-color:#cde4f1;padding:10px 5px 30px 5px;width:70%;">
<p><strong>Ut varius lorem mi, non tristique felis hendrerit id.</strong></p>
<select>
<option>--Choose--</option>
<option>3 parts Medications </option>
<option>4 parts Medications </option>
<option>Medication page</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Go to what specific pages? What urls and how are the urls related/linked to the options.... Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please refer to: [Ask]. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before posting.

Comment: well I'm just testing the code right now so I can use any url just as a sample right now. I'm just looking to practice building something like this and looking for some help.

Comment: well this is my first time here so please forgive me for not following protocol

Comment: I added the 'html' tag and edited your Subject line for better clarity.  I noticed though, that you also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before posting.

Comment: Well I suggest you start by learning basic javascript. Once you have an understanding of it try again and if you still have problems return here and explain what you have, what you wish to achieve and show what you have tried. This site isn't to give people tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freebie using jQuery and `data` attributes on each `<option>`. Try to research a bit more next time before forming a question here, though!

```js
$('#go').click(function() {
  location.href = $('#menu').find('option:selected').data('url');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background-color:#cde4f1;padding:10px 5px 30px 5px;width:70%;">
  <p><strong>Ut varius lorem mi, non tristique felis hendrerit id.</strong></p>

  <select id="menu">
    <option>--Choose--</option>
    <option data-url="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</option>
    <option data-url="http://bing.com">Bing</option>
  </select>

  <button id="go" type="button">Go</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     function redirectUrl()
        {    var url = document.getElementById("selectUrl").value;
          if(url!="")
           {
             // window.location.replace(url); this also works
             window.location.href=url;
           }
        }
</script>

<div style="background-color:#cde4f1;padding:10px 5px 30px 5px;width:70%;">
<p><strong>Ut varius lorem mi, non tristique felis hendrerit id.</strong></p>
<select id="selectUrl" >
<option value="">--Choose--</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">3 parts Medications </option>
<option value="http://stackoverflow.com">4 parts Medications </option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="redirectUrl()">Go</button>
</div>
```